# A more streamline, efficient way to split a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

is there a faster, more efficient way to split rows in a list. My current setup isn't slow but does take longer than I think to split the whole list, maybe due to how many iterations it is required to go through the whole list.

I currently have the code below

```
found_reader = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter='\n', engine='c')
loaded_list = found_reader    
for i in range(len(loaded_list)):
            loaded_email_list = loaded_email_list + [loaded_list[i].split(':')[0]]
```

I just would like a method to do the above in the quickest but efficient time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you do that efficiently if both `loaded_list` and `loaded_email_list` were regular lists (it may need slight adaptation for whatever it is that Pandas uses):

```
loaded_email_list += [x.partition(':')[0] for x in loaded_list]
```

Why this is better:

- It iterates over the list directly, instead of using `range`, `len`, and an index variable
- It uses `partition`, which stops looking after the first `:`, instead of `split`, which walks the whole string
- It uses a list comprehension to create the new list all at once, rather than creating and concatenating a bunch of single-element lists
- It uses `x += y`, instead of `x = x + y`, which could theoretically be faster if its `__iadd__` is more efficient than assigning its `__add__` result back to itself.

Comment: Much appreciated. Funny enough I sort of solved it with this -     loaded_email_list = [row.split(':', 1)[0] for row in loaded_list].

But I read what you said about using partition over split and it makes sense.